# ExecuteIndirect crashed on AMD GPU when expanding indirect command buffer

Tags: directx, directx-12

I try to use ExecuteIndirect for drawing my instances.

Here is my code:

```
struct IndirectCommand
{
    D3D12_GPU_VIRTUAL_ADDRESS materialBufferAddress;
    D3D12_GPU_VIRTUAL_ADDRESS instanceBufferAddress;
    D3D12_DRAW_INDEXED_ARGUMENTS drawArguments;
};  // byte stride: 40

// code for initializing command signature
void InstanceManager::InitIndirectBuffer()
{
    D3D12_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT_DESC indirectDescs[3] = {};
    indirectDescs[0].Type = D3D12_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT_TYPE_CONSTANT_BUFFER_VIEW;
    indirectDescs[0].ConstantBufferView.RootParameterIndex = cMaterialPass;
    indirectDescs[1].Type = D3D12_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT_TYPE_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW;
    indirectDescs[1].ShaderResourceView.RootParameterIndex = cInstancePass;
    indirectDescs[2].Type = D3D12_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT_TYPE_DRAW_INDEXED;

    D3D12_COMMAND_SIGNATURE_DESC commandSignatureDesc = {};
    commandSignatureDesc.pArgumentDescs = indirectDescs;
    commandSignatureDesc.NumArgumentDescs = _countof(indirectDescs);
    commandSignatureDesc.ByteStride = sizeof(IndirectCommand);

    ThrowIfFailed(Engine::GetApp()->GetDevice()->CreateCommandSignature(&commandSignatureDesc, Engine::GetApp()->GetRootSignature(), IID_PPV_ARGS(&mCommandSignature)));
}
```

Appending indirect command buffer:

```
void AppendIndirectCommandBuffer()
{
    // wait for gpu
    Engine::GetApp()->ResetCommandList();
    Engine::GetApp()->ExecuteCommand();
    Engine::GetApp()->FlushCommandQueue();

    for (int i = 0; i < gNumFrameResources; i++)
    {
        // alloc upload heap
        Engine::GetApp()->GetFrameManager().GetFrameResource(i)->AppendUploadBuffer<IndirectCommand>(mIndirectBufferUpload[i]
            , mLastIndirectUploadCount[i]
            , mIndirectCount
            , false);

        // alloc default heap
        Engine::GetApp()->GetFrameManager().GetFrameResource(i)->AppendDefaultBuffer<IndirectCommand>(mIndirectBufferDefault[i]
            , mLastIndirectDefaultCount[i]
            , mIndirectCount++
            , false);
    }
    UpdateIndirectData(_obj);
    // code for appending indirect command buffer 
}
```

Update indirect command buffer data:

```
void UpdateIndirectData(GameObject _obj)
{
    UINT matCBByteSize = d3dUtil::CalcConstantBufferByteSize(sizeof(MaterialData));
    UINT insCBByteSize = sizeof(InstanceData);

    for (int i = 0; i < gNumFrameResources; i++)
    {
        if (Engine::GetApp()->GetFrameManager().GetFrameResource(i) != NULL)
        {
            string _matName = _obj->GetComponent<RenderObject>()->GetMaterialName();
            string _geoName = _obj->GetComponent<RenderObject>()->GetGeometryName();
            Material *mat = Engine::GetApp()->GetMaterialManager().GetMaterial(_matName);

            if (mat != nullptr)
            {
                IndirectCommand data;

                data.materialBufferAddress = Engine::GetApp()->GetMaterialManager().GetMaterialBuffer(i)->Resource()->GetGPUVirtualAddress()
                + matCBByteSize*mat->GetMatBufferIndex();

                data.instanceBufferAddress = mInstanceBuffer[i]->Resource()->GetGPUVirtualAddress() + mInstanceIndex[_obj->GetID()] * insCBByteSize;

                data.drawArguments.BaseVertexLocation = mDrawArgs[_geoName].BaseVertexLocation;
                data.drawArguments.IndexCountPerInstance = mDrawArgs[_geoName].IndexCount;
                data.drawArguments.StartIndexLocation = mDrawArgs[_geoName].StartIndexLocation;
                data.drawArguments.StartInstanceLocation = 0;
                data.drawArguments.InstanceCount = 1;

                int indirectIndex = mIndirectIndex[_obj->GetID()];
                mIndirectCommand[indirectIndex] = data;    // an array of indirect command, size is set to 1000 temporarily

                // copy to default heap
                D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_DATA commandData = {};
                commandData.pData = reinterpret_cast<UINT8*>(&mIndirectCommand[0]);
                commandData.RowPitch = sizeof(IndirectCommand) * mIndirectCount;
                commandData.SlicePitch = commandData.RowPitch;
                UpdateSubresources<1U>(Engine::GetApp()->GetCommandList(), mIndirectBufferDefault[i]->Resource(), mIndirectBufferUpload[i]->Resource(), 0, 0, 1, &commandData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Last, executeindirect

```
void DrawIndirectInstance()
{
    Engine::GetApp()->GetCommandList()->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &mGeometry->VertexBufferView());
    Engine::GetApp()->GetCommandList()->IASetIndexBuffer(&mGeometry->IndexBufferView16());
    Engine::GetApp()->GetCommandList()->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    // just set a pso for testing, I haven't group my instances by material yet
    ID3D12PipelineState *pso = Engine::GetApp()->GetMaterialManager().GetMaterialPSO("test");
    Engine::GetApp()->GetCommandList()->SetPipelineState(pso);

    int frameIndex = Engine::GetApp()->GetFrameManager().GetCurrFrameIndex();
    auto indirectBuffer = mIndirectBufferUpload[frameIndex].get();

    auto materialBuffer = Engine::GetApp()->GetMaterialManager().GetMaterialBuffer(frameIndex);
    Engine::GetApp()->GetCommandList()->SetGraphicsRootConstantBufferView(cMaterialPass, materialBuffer->Resource()->GetGPUVirtualAddress());
    Engine::GetApp()->GetCommandList()->SetGraphicsRootShaderResourceView(cInstancePass, mInstanceBuffer[frameIndex]->Resource()->GetGPUVirtualAddress());

    Engine::GetApp()->GetCommandList()->ResourceBarrier(1
    , &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(indirectBuffer->Resource(), D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT));

    Engine::GetApp()->GetCommandList()->ExecuteIndirect(mCommandSignature.Get()
    , mIndirectCount
    , indirectBuffer->Resource()
    , 0
    , nullptr
    , 0);

    Engine::GetApp()->GetCommandList()->ResourceBarrier(1
    , &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(indirectBuffer->Resource(), D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST));
}
```

I use my SceneManager to load a scene. If a gameobject is a render object.
My system will call AppendIndirectCommandBuffer() and copy data into indirect command buffer.

ExecuteIndirect() will work great if I do not clone my gameobject after initialization of my scene.

And I try to clone my gameobject at runtime(in my Update()).

My system calls AppendIndirectCommandBuffer() again to resize indirect command buffer and copies new data to buffer.

After cloning gameobject for a few second, my system starts to glitch and result in TDR on my R9 380.

But works properly on both WARP and intel gpu.

And I don't know why :(.

How to solve this problem? I really want to make good use of indirect drawing.

Thanks!

**Update**

A upload heap resource can't transit to D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_INDIRECT_ARGUMENT.

I create a default type heap, and use upload heap to copy data to it.

I tried debug layer, no errors are returned from it.
I tried GBV and only got two errors:

```
D3D12 ERROR: GPU-BASED VALIDATION: Draw, Uninitialized root argument accessed. Shader Stage: VERTEX, Root Parameter Index: [2], Draw Index: [0], Shader Code: Forward.hlsl(21,2-42), Asm Instruction Range: [0x114-0x13b], Asm Operand Index: [3], Command List: 0x00000134BB3C1EE0:'Unnamed ID3D12GraphicsCommandList Object', SRV/UAV/CBV Descriptor Heap: 0x00000134AE6DD020:'Unnamed ID3D12DescriptorHeap Object', Sampler Descriptor Heap: <not set>, Pipeline State: 0x00000134BB5CB540:'Unnamed ID3D12PipelineState Object',  [ EXECUTION ERROR #935: GPU_BASED_VALIDATION_ROOT_ARGUMENT_UNINITIALIZED]
D3D12 ERROR: GPU-BASED VALIDATION: Draw, Uninitialized root argument accessed. Shader Stage: VERTEX, Root Parameter Index: [1], Draw Index: [0], Shader Code: Forward.hlsl(37,2-41), Asm Instruction Range: [0x8c0-0x8e3], Asm Operand Index: [2], Command List: 0x000001D0D7B70860:'Unnamed ID3D12GraphicsCommandList Object', SRV/UAV/CBV Descriptor Heap: 0x000001D0D7AC6C80:'Unnamed ID3D12DescriptorHeap Object', Sampler Descriptor Heap: <not set>, Pipeline State: 0x000001D0D7BBF450:'Unnamed ID3D12PipelineState Object',  [ EXECUTION ERROR #935: GPU_BASED_VALIDATION_ROOT_ARGUMENT_UNINITIALIZED]
```

And a warning:

```
D3D12 WARNING: ID3D12CommandList::ExecuteIndirect: GPU-based validation is not supported for ExecuteIndirect that changes root bindings. All further GPU-based validation output may not be reliable. [ EXECUTION WARNING #1000: GPU_BASED_VALIDATION_UNSUPPORTED]
```

After I call the following functions, these two errors are gone.

```
Engine::GetApp()->GetCommandList()->SetGraphicsRootConstantBufferView(cMaterialPass, materialBuffer->Resource()->GetGPUVirtualAddress());
Engine::GetApp()->GetCommandList()->SetGraphicsRootShaderResourceView(cInstancePass, mInstanceBuffer[frameIndex]->Resource()->GetGPUVirtualAddress());
```

Despite making these modification, it still doesn't work properly.

Comment: Have you try the debug layer and gpu based validation. I do not see the state transition to indirect argument in your code that is necessary for some cache flush on the GCN hardware.

Comment: This is the cost that comes with the level of low-level exposure DirectX 12 provides: You need to be able to troubleshoot and validate your specific application across a suite of hardware. The Direct3D debug layer is always a good starting place, as is trying WARP12, but really you need to have a number of different machines to try out to diagnose if the problem is the driver or your app, and then reach out to the hardware vendor to try out a beta driver. See [Anatomy of Direct3D 12 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2016/08/16/anatomy-of-direct3d-12-create-device/).

Comment: Also be sure you have a mix of hardware feature tiers as that can make a big difference as well. I've hit a number of problems with [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12) that only repro on Tier 1 resource binding systems, but work fine on Tier 2 or better. This is largely the reason why using DirectX 12 before you've really pushed the limits of a DirectX 11 implementation may not be a productive use of time for a project. Of course, if it's a learning exercise then as long as you have the background you are learning some good lessons now.

Comment: @galop1n I made a update. Would you please take a look? thanks.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thank you for your suggestion. I think I would only initialize the devices which support feature 12_0 and 12_1 in the future. And yes, I'm just practicing now and deeply interested in this.

Comment: The bulk of GPUs that support DirectX 12 currently are feature level 11_0 or 11_1. You can check the resource tier by using ``CheckFeatureSupport`` if you want to exclude Tier 1 resource systems although that's likely to result in a lot of customer confusion if this is a shipping product.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I find the reason!

Bug is from my instance data buffer.

```
Engine::GetApp()->GetFrameManager().GetFrameResource(i)->AppendUploadBuffer<InstanceData>(mInstanceBuffer[i]
            , mLastInstanceCount[i]
            , mInstanceCount
            , false);
```

After calling this, **memory address is changed**.
If I set indirect command buffer data with the following code, GPU will crash.

```
data.instanceBufferAddress = mInstanceBuffer[i]->Resource()->GetGPUVirtualAddress() + mInstanceIndex[_obj->GetID()] * insCBByteSize;
```

So I need to either create a fixed-size instance buffer at initialization (address won't change) or update all previous indirect command data after cloning my gameobject (would kill performance).

Sorry for asking a stupid question :$.

Comment: Mistakes happen, using a deleted resource in d3d12 is one of them because of the lack of safeguard. You have options to not redo your addresses in the indirect buffer. If you use reserved resources, you can create the instance data resource large enough for worst case, and commit pages as you add instances. That way, the gpu virtual address will remain constant.